# How to add a:hover css function to this code?

Tags: css

I would like to know what would be the correct way to add a hover color having this code:

```
.newsletter .newsletter-submit {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 3px;
background-image: url(widget-neutral/button.png);
color: #fff;
}
```

Right now when I put the mouse over the link, I see the button in white. What I would like is to delete that white color when hovering.

Comment: CSS isn't very useful without the markup that it targets. Post your HTML in your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
.newsletter .newsletter-submit:hover {
    color: black;/*Or whatever Color*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this simpler selector if you not need to match any `.newsletter-submit` element that is a descendant of `.newsletter element`.

```
.newsletter-submit:hover {
    color: red;
    }
```

More on CSS Selectors here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html